# Having trouble injecting keyboard events to FLTK

Tags: events, fltk

I have a system with no keyboard.  I can connect a keyboard, but ultimately the inputs come from a custom keypad which is not a HID device, it sends serial data which I can interpret and decode to determine if the user pressed Up, Down, Left, Right, or Enter.

Right now all I have is a Fl_Window, with two Fl_Button widgets.  Focus is set for one of the buttons and callbacks are defined for these buttons.  I know that if I attach a real keyboard, and use the arrow keys I can change focus from button to button.  I do have to hit SPACE to activate a button.

My problem is determining how to cause these key presses using code when I decode the outcome form the embedded key pad.  Because in deployment, there will be no actual keyboard.

What I've tried is to invoke int Fl_Window::handle(int) and not really had success.  I've also tried to invoke int Fl::handle(int, Fl_Window *) and not had success.

Here are code examples:

```
if((ret = Fl::handle(FL_Left, window)) == 0)
```

That compiles, but I find that I get zero back, implying that it did not process the event.

```
if((ret = Fl_Window::handle(FL_Right)) == 0)
```

That does not compile, informing me that it "cannot call member function virtual int Fl_Window::handle(int) without object"

I'm thinking that the "int event" actually ought to be FL_KEYDOWN.

That logic leaves me to wonder though how I "set" event_key().  For instance, there are API functions to get that when one has a handler, but I do not wish to get that; I wish to cause that event to occur.

Is my only option here to figure out how to emulate a HID or make some type of virtual HID where I then cause the keyboard events to occur?

I do not feel I require a handler function in my application, I'm fine with the default behaviors which occur and cause my callback functions to be invoked.  My problem is that I can't "cause" these events to occur.

Comment: Have a look at "Demonstrate keyboard press/release" in http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#KeyPressRelease

Comment: You can cause the events to occur by using send.

Comment: Thanks for citing the example, I think it shows how to write a custom handler, I don't believe I need that, I just need to know how to cause the events to occur.  I see the next comment about send(); and the FLTK documentation states that it is the preferred wrapper for handle().  OK, in trying to use that I can't quite find the syntax, nor any examples.  I can't get it to compile if I declare it as Fl_Widget::send(), Fl_Window::send(), or Fl::send().

Comment: Sorry: I'm switching between FLTK1 and FLTK2.  send is an FLTK2 thing.  On FLTK1, send is a static.  One way around it is to get the fltk source and take off the static.  Another way is to set Fl::e_keysym and then call the handler.  Let me know if you need an example - are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Sure an example would be great, I will try this suggestion.  I'm using Linux.  There's a FLTK2?  Maybe I'll switch to that.  Checking that out now, my main desire with that one would be if it can work directly to the framebuffer.

Comment: I got it working by setting the e_keysym.  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: There is an FLTK2 and an FLTK3.  Hardly anyone uses FLTK2 - if you use it, you're on your own.  I have yet to try FLTK3.  If you want help on FLTK, best keep to FLTK1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the desired key to `e_keysym`, then dispatch a `FL_KEYDOWN` event using `Fl::handle_()`. (`Fl::handle()` will not generate the followup `FL_SHORTCUT` event.)

```
Fl::e_keysym = FL_Left;
Fl::handle_(FL_KEYDOWN, window);
// sleep() and/or Fl::wait() as appropriate
Fl::handle_(FL_KEYUP, window);
```